# JS - ReferenceError: produto_editar is not defined

Tags: php, javascript

Temos um projeto antigo `PHP` e `JS` que funcionava no `Wamp 2.2.` sem erros. Não conheço muito de `JS` ou `PHP` e precisamos fazer uma pequena alteração.

Para atualizar o projeto, a ideia é atualizar para `wampserver 3.0`, mas o mesmo código começou a gerar um erro que acho que tem a ver com atualização feita do `Wamp`.

Na tela onde se selecionam os produtos, a função que é chamada ao clicar na linha do produto para editá-lo, agora retorna um erro como se não estivesse definida:

```
ReferenceError: produto_editar is not defined
```

Referencia na tabela:

```
<a class="ir editar" onclick="produto_editar('.$res['id_produto'].');" > > <b>title="Editar dados do produto">Editar registro</a>
```

Função:

```
//Função envia página edição do produto
function paciente_editar(valor){                     
    var pedido_request = new Request({
        'method':'post',
        'noCache':false,
        onComplete:function(a){
            location.href ="cadastro_produto.php?acao=editar&id=" + valor;
        }
    });
    pedido_request.send('');                    
}
```

Não faço ideia de como resolver.

Comment: Realmente está errado. No onclick tem produto_editar e a função que você colocou é paciente_editar. Ou seja produto editar não existe.

Comment: Você tem razão, troquei o nome para testar. Existe outro erro que não vi? Valeu!

Comment: Funcionou, valeu!